# What is the right way to define a function?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, definition, education

Most authors define functions this way:

Given the sets $A$ and $B$. A relation is a subset of $A\times B$. Then given a relation $R$, we define $Dom_R=\{x|(x,y)\in R\}$ and $Img_R=\{x|(y,x)\in R\}$.

Then a function from $A$ to $B$, $f:A\rightarrow B$, *is a relation* with the property that each element of the domain is related to exactly one element of the image, such that $Dom_f=A$ and $Img_f\subseteq B$.

Well, if we accept those definitions, functions are just special sets of ordered pairs (remember, functions are relations and, as far as I know, this is emphasized in most books). Specifying the set of inputs and the set of outputs is just necessary when describing functions using the *axiom of replacement* of ZFC, but what really dictates which set is which is its elements. Thus, for example, the function \begin{align}f:\{0,1\}&\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\0&\mapsto2\\1&\mapsto 3\end{align}
and the function \begin{align}g:\{0,1\}&\rightarrow \{2,3\}\\0&\mapsto2\\1&\mapsto 3\end{align}
are the same, since both are the set $\{(0,2),(1,3)\}$. The thing is that $g$ is considered a surjection while $f$ is not. And this is really a problem.

Furthermore, the concept of a graph of a function $Gr(f)$, which is the set $\{(x,f(x))|x\in Dom_f\}$, loses its sense, since the graph would be the function itself.

Wouldn't be much better to define the function as an ordered triple $(A,B,f)$, where $A$ is the domain, $B$ the codomain and $f$ the relation with the properties described above? It's different, since $f$ itself would not be a function, but only the ordered triple would. Then we could define $Gr((A,B,f)):=f$. In this case, the graph of the function would be a relation instead of the function.
Also, the notation $f:A\rightarrow B$ could still be used to describe $(A,B,f)$.

To force the function to be a relation, we would have to define relation the same way: the relation would also be an ordered triple $(A,B,R)$, where $R \subseteq A\times B$. But in this case, the relation is not a set of ordered pairs, but the 'graph of the relation' is.

The third and last option is to define both relation and function as a set of ordered pairs, as usually. But although injectivity is a property of a function, surjectivity would rather be a relation between a function $f$ and another given set $B$ called codomain.

Am I getting it right? If so, what is the best way to define a function? Define a function not as a relation but a triple or define a relation not as  a set of ordered pairs but a triple? Or another option?

Comment: The correct way to define a function is as a triple $(A,f,B)$ where $A$ is the domain, $B$ is the codomain, and $f\subseteq A\times B$ satisfying the familiar conditions.

Comment: It depends on the context you are working in. In settheory functions are identified as special subsets of $A\times B$. In the theory of categories $f:=\langle A,G_f,B\rangle$ is a function with domain $A$, codomain $B$ and graph $G_f\subseteq A\times B$. In my view the best strategy is just to go along with these (mastered) differences.

Comment: Also for a set $A$ domain (and codomain) can be defined. $A$ is not demanded to be a relation for that: $x\in\text{Dom}(A)$ if $\langle x,y\rangle\in A$ for some $y$.

Comment: drhab. The problem is, in settheory, it seems that surjectivity is treated as a property of the function. And I guess that would be wrong...

Comment: @drhab: What? How are you defining $\langle x,y\rangle$?

Comment: @MPW As an ordered pair.

Comment: It might "seem". However in e.g. replacement/substitution surjectivity of a function $f$ is not really applied. One only says that the collection $\{f(a)\mid a\in A\}$ is by axiom a set. This formulation avoids surjectivity. When "functions" are identified with "graphs of functions"  then the concept "surjectivity of a function" actually stops to exist.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29#Alternative_definition_of_a_function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to proceed is the following, starting from the concept of *ordered couple*, defined set-theoretically in the usual way.

We define when a set is a *relation* :

> $R \text { is a relation } \ ↔ ∀z(z \in R → ∃x \ ∃y \ (z = \langle x,y \rangle \ ))$.

Thus, a *relation* is a set of *ordered couples*.

As usual, we write $xRy$ for $\langle x,y \rangle \in R$.

We define :

> $\mathcal {Dom}_R = \{ x : \exists y \ (x R y) \}$

and :

> $\mathcal {Img}_R = \{ y : \exists x \ (x R y) \}$.

Then we define when a relation is a *function* :

> $f \text { is a function } ↔ f \text { is a relation } \land ∀x \ ∀y \ ∀z \ (xfy ∧ xfz → y=z)$.

Up to now, no "$A$s" nor "$B$s".

Then we say :

> $f \text { is a function from } A \text { into } B \leftrightarrow f \text { is a function } \land \mathcal {Dom}_f=A \land \mathcal {Img}_f \subseteq B$;
>
> $f \text { is a function from } A \text { onto } B \leftrightarrow f \text { is a function } \land \mathcal {Dom}_f=A \land \mathcal {Img}_f = B$.

---

See : Patrick Suppes, [Axiomatic set theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=skTCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA88) (1960), page 88.

See also : Kenneth Kunen, [The Foundations of Mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=_B_oQQAACAAJ) (2009), page 24-25.

---

Regarding your example, with this approach we have that $f=g$, where $f$ is a function from $\{ 0,1 \}$ **into** $\mathbb R$, while $g$ is a function from $\{ 0,1 \}$ **onto** $\{ 2,3 \}$.

In this case, *surjectivity* is not an "intrinsic" property of $g$; the applicability of the word "onto" depends both on $g$ and on the set $B$, not just on $g$.

---

A different approach is possible, of course; see :

- Robert Goldblatt, [Topoi : The Categorial Analysis of Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=hLPDAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA19) (2ed - 1984) , page 19 :

> modify the definition of function in the following way. Firstly for sets $A$ and $B$ we define the *product set* or *Cartesian product* of $A$ and $B$ to be the set of all ordered pairs whose first elements are in $A$ and second elements in $B$. This is denoted $A \times B$, and so
>
> $$A \times B = \{ \langle x, y \rangle : x \in A \land y \in B \}.$$
>
> A function is now defined as a triple $f = \langle A, B, R \rangle$, where $R \subseteq A \times B$ is a relation from $A$ to $B$ (the *graph* of $f$), such that for each $x \in A$ there is one and only one $y \in B$ for which $\langle x, y \rangle \in R$. Thus the domain ($A$) and codomain ($B$) are incorporated in the definition of a function from the outset.

---

With this approach, the two "objects $\langle \{ 0,1 \}, \mathbb R, f \rangle$ and  $\langle \{ 0,1 \}, \{ 2,3 \}, f \rangle$ are not the "same" function.

In this second case, *surjectivity* is an "intrinsic" property of $\langle \{ 0,1 \}, \{ 2,3 \}, f \rangle$.

Comment: Wouldn't that be my third (and last) option? In your case, we can also say that surjection is a relation between a function $f$ and a set $B$, right?

Comment: Interesting! So what's really wrong in all of this is to treat surjection as a property of the function.

All of the options I gave works, but if that's the best and the standard, then I will prefer to use it.

In the comments above, they say function are defined as triples in Theory of Categories. Why don't mathematicians come into an agreement and use one universal definition? Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Really, your answer is great and it will be accepted (again) soon! You provided really good sources too. But, let me get this straight: as far as I have seen, it seems everybody works with function as it was defined as a triple, and there is the problem of the identity/inclusion function as your source pointed out... and yet the standard definition is the first one you posted (only set of ordered pairs)!?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your $g$ is surjective and your $f$ is not, using your definition of function, is that the relation $g$ is taken from $\{0,1\}\times\{2,3\}$ while $f$ is taken from $\{0,1\}\times\mathbb R$.

So $\operatorname{Img}_g$ covers $\{2,3\}$, but $\operatorname{Img}_f$ does not cover $\mathbb R$.

Comment: So surjectivity does not depend only of the function, but how we describe them using the Axiom of Replacement (which can be in a non-unique way)? Because $f$ and $g$ are the same set.

Comment: In the end, @IttayWeiss is correct. The function is not fully defined until you specify (1) the domain, (2) the range, and (3) the rule of assignment. The rule of assignment amounts to the list of ordered pairs you furnish. That, alone, is not a function. The domain and range furnish a context in which to decide if two functions are equal. So equality of the set of ordered pairs **is not enough** either to define a function or to determine if a function equals a surjective function.

Comment: If that's correct and someone provide a proper answer explaining why it is correct and providing sources about this definition in ZFC, then I will undo my last acceptance. Although all of the options given works well (if we also change some other concepts), we have to have a standard. I believe this is too important to overlook.

Comment: You know what, I will undo my acceptance, so this will be an open problem again. If no one gives another answer, I am going to accept it again within a month.

Comment: There are clearly different ways to define "function". Defining $f:A\to B$ as as a certain kind of subset of $A\times B$ , means that $f:A\to C$ is the same function when $B\subset C$. This can be a convenience or an annoyance, depending on context. Or depending on your stylistic preference. Textbooks are not unanimous on the definition.Textbooks on set theory are not even unanimous on what an ordered pair is, although $(x,y)=\{x,\{x,y\}\}$  seems to be the favorite.

Comment: @user254665 : What you're doing is really just abuse of notation. They simply aren't "the same function". What you really mean, is that if $\iota:B\to C$ is the inclusion map (since $B\subset C$), and if you have $\hat{f}:A\to B$ and $f:A\to C$, then the functions $f$ and $\iota\circ \hat{f}$ are the same.

Comment: To a set theorist they're still the same set,aren't they?

Comment: @user254665: Do you think the real number $0$ is the same as the complex number $0$? The answer is, technically, no. But we usually choose to ignore that we identify the reals with a specific set of complex numbers. It is often convenient to ignore the distinction because this sort of distinction is often crippling in practice if it is made explicit in every instance. However, when technical detail is crucial to understanding a subtle argument, it may need to be made explicit. Otherwise, we have what is usually called "hand waving".