# Advantages of considering a function as a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, reference-request

**Can anyone give me some reference (could be a book, paper, or even notes)**, in which the author writes about the advantages of defining a function as a set for mathematics in general?

Let $f(x) = x + 1$ be the law of a function.

Let $X \times Y \neq \varnothing$

**(a)** We can write $f = \{(x; x+1) : x \in X\}$

**(b)** The fact is that, without this language we can understand a function as a simple law that associates a number to another, or even in more informal ways as a machine that transforms nunbers.

I need a material that shows why **(a)** it's better than **(b)** for mathematics in general.

Comment: What is $Y$ in your question?

Comment: I just wanted to show that the function emerges of the Cartesian product of this two sets $X$ and $Y$. or $f \subset X \times Y$.

Comment: *Economy of thought*. We can start from *function* as primitive; see [Category Theory](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/category-theory/).

Comment: When you write the function as a set of tuples or vectors this is named, in some books, the graph of the function $f$, not the function itself.

Comment: So you are saying that in this case $Y=\{x+1\mid x\in X\}$? Or $Y=\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$? In some definitions of function, that matters. That shows why a formal, clear definition is necessary.

Comment: You can assume the concept of *function* as primitive (i.e. undefined) instead of defining it with set theory machinery (that is, assuming the concept of *set* as ubdefined). **But** if you try to "elucidate" it as "a law that associates a number to another ...", you will easily find that the set theory definition is quite natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is so deeply ingrained since the early 20th century that it is hardly ever argued explicitly anymore. For one thing, it does away with the logical absurdities that arise from such horrible concepts as "multivalued functions". It is very hard to keep a consistent notation if you start from a general relationship (such as an algebraic equation in $x$ and $y$) and try to prove that it actually defines a function $y=f(x)$ unless you somehow identify functions with their graphs.

Please note that the usual definition of a relation (function or otherwise) is not that is *is* a graph: to be consistent the definition is an ordered triplet consisting of two sets and a subset of their cartesian product.

*(Update based on some comments)*

In secondary school teaching the recent trend is to *avoid* sets as an explicit concept. In that context useful metaphors for single-valued functions are black boxes with an input and output channel, and even little hand cranks illustrating the "work" of a tranformation.

For a balanced view on the interplay between these two approaches, see for instance section 12.5 in B. Baumslag, "Fundamentals of Teaching Mathematics at University Level," Imperial College Press 2000.

Comment: "This is so deeply ingrained .. that it is hardly ever argued explicitly"  Perhaps that's a problem and it should be stated more explicitely.  I first encountered functions in the second grade as "function boxes" where you plug something in and and apply a rule (the drawings even had little handcranks on them).  When I first encountered them as sets in *graduate* school it threw me for a loop.  Especically in topology as transformations.  Would have *really* helped if I had thought of them as *equivalently* as sets as well.

Comment: Regarding the "usual definition of a relation or function", you can see also [What is the right way to define a function?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1473169/what-is-the-right-way-to-define-a-function).

Comment: @fleablood Teaching functions without set theory traces its pedigree to the venerable Dirichlet; but set theory really simplifies the formalism when turning the handcrank only once can result in several little packages coming out of the box.

Comment: @fleablood: Your comment shows how different things have apparently become. I don't think I heard the mathematical term "function" (at school, at least; this is in the U.S.A.) until 7th grade, maybe not until 8th grade (ages 13-14; around 1971-73), but functions were defined as sets of ordered pairs pretty much from the beginning. Certainly they were done this way in my 9th grade Algebra 1 class (used Dolciani's **Modern Algebra Structure. Book One**), and functions were even treated this way in the college algebra and precalculus texts I taught from throughout the 1980s.

Comment: "apparently become"?  New Math did not last that long and was not deemed successful and has become a forgotten footnote in history since.

Comment: "but set theory really simplifies the formalism when turning the handcrank only once can result in several little packages coming out of the box."  Really?  I see it the exact oppositely.  With ordered pairs (a,5)(b,7)(a,3)(c,5) are perfectly acceptable and to say (a,3)(a,5) is impossible because it has two of the same letters but different numbers while (a,3)(b,3) with two of the same numbers coming from different letters is just fine seems capricious and arbitrary.  But a little crank with a handle can never pop out multiple packages.  You but ingredients in and pull  crank and get output.

Comment: @fleablood the New Math critic: one should distinguish between on the one hand the professional mathematics community, where sets have arrived centre stage in the 1930s (think Polish topologists) and haven't left since, and on the other hand secondary school mathematics, where sets were only introduced in the 1960s-1970s depending on your continent, and where public outrage has pushed them to the background 20-30 years later, the exact timing again depending on your mileage.

Comment: @fleablood with the hand crank: exactly, a little crank is not a useful metaphor for naturally multivalued functions such as the square root.

Comment: I'm *not* a new math critic.  I learned under new math and *loved* it.  However the universal consensus was it was a complete failure.  Tom Lehrer says, and I agree with him, the trouble was it taught abstract theoretical math by people who didn't understand it who assumed math was for practical vocational purposes.  @Justpassingby I'm a bit confused.  multivalued functions aren't functions.  Only one thing can come out of a crank.

Comment: @fleablood: Out of curiosity, this morning I looked at some copies of the Dolciani algebra books I have on my bookshelves (dating from around 1972 or so). The Algebra 1 book doesn't mention functions as sets of ordered pairs when functions are first introduced, but later in the book they are defined as a certain type of relation, where a relation is a set of ordered pairs. The Algebra 2 book defines relations as sets of ordered pairs and functions as a certain type of relation the first time functions are dealt with. Also, College Algebra and Precalculus texts I've **(continued)**

Comment: **(continuation)** taught out of from the early 1980s through the early 2000s all defined functions as certain types of sets of ordered pairs (or at least said this is one interpretation of what functions are). Finally, it occurs to me now that just about every 2nd year (U.S.A. college) "transition to advanced mathematics" text hits this idea very heavily, which makes it especially surprising to me that you didn't see it until graduate school (or maybe I'm misunderstanding your comment).

Answer (score 3):

You can see :

- John von Neumann, *Eine Axiomatisierung der Mengenlehre*, (1925), translated as *An axiomatization of set theory*, into : Jean van Heijenoort (editor), [From Frege to Godel : A Source Book in Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=v4tBTBlU05sC&pg=PA396) (1967), page 393-on :

> We prefer, however, to axiomatize not "set" but "function". The latter notion 
>   certainly includes the former. [...] We consider two domains of objects, that of " arguments" and that of" functions". (Both words are, of course, to be taken in a purely formal way, as if they had no meaning.) The two domains are not identical, but they partly overlap. (There are "argument-functions", which belong to both domains.)
>
> Now a two-variable operation $[x,y]$ (read "the value of the function $x$ for the argument $y$"), whose first variable $x$ must always be a "function" and whose second variable $y$ must always be an "argument", is defined in these domains. What is formed by means of it is always an "argument", $[x,y]$.
>
> The operation $[x,y]$ corresponds to a procedure that is that is encountered everywhere in mathematics, namely, the formation, from a function $f$ (which must be carefully distinguished from its values $f(x)$!) and an argument $x$, of the value $f(x)$ of the function $f$ for the argument $x$. Instead of $f(x)$ we write $[f,x]$.

---

You can see also :

- Hendrik Pieter Barendregt, [The Lambda Calculus : Its Syntax and Semantics](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZdydJZVue50C) (rev ed - 1984), page 3 :

> The lambda calculus is a type free theory about functions as *rules*, rather 
>   than as graphs. "Functions as rules" is the old fashioned notion of function and refers to the process of going from argument to value, a process coded by a definition. The idea, usually attributed to Dirichlet, that functions could also be considered as graphs, that is, as sets of pairs of argument and value, was an important mathematical contribution.  Nevertheless the $\lambda$-calculus regards functions again as rules in order to stress their *computational* aspects.

---

For [Category theory](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/category-theory/), you can see :

- Steve Awodey, [Category Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=zLs8BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA3) (2nd ed : 2010), page 3 :

> *What is category theory?* As a first approximation, one could say that category theory is the mathematical study of (abstract) *algebras of functions*.
>
> We begin by considering functions between sets. I am not going to say here what
>   a function is, anymore than what a set is. Instead, we will assume a working
>   knowledge of these terms. They can in fact be defined using category theory, but
>   that is not our purpose here.